# Undefined method '[]' nilLNilClass for Adding columns in multiarrays

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I am trying to solve the Projecteuler #11 but I am running into an error when I'm trying to create a function to calculate the multiplication of every 4 numbers in a column. I am getting an error:

```
    Project11.rb:59:in `sumvertical': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMeth
odError)
```

I feel like there is something I am easily overlooking here. I appreciate the help!

```
#project #11 http://projecteuler.net/problem=11
grid="08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48"

grid=grid.split()
grid=grid.collect {|s| s.to_i}
multiarray=[]
i = 0
e = 19
until e > 400
    multiarray << grid[i..e]
    i+= 20
    e+= 20
end

def sumhorizontal(x) #checks sum of all horizontal 4 elements
sum = 0
    x.each {|a|
        i=0
        e=3
        while e < a.length
            if a[i..e].inject(:*) > sum
                sum = a[i..e].inject(:*)
                i += 1
                e += 1
            else
                i += 1
                e += 1
            end
        end
    }
    return sum
end

def sumvertical(x)
sum = 0
    i=0
    e=0
    while e < x.length  #Will break once the end point is longer than the length of an array
        until i > 20   #Checks the first column      
            if x[i][e]*x[i+1][e]*x[i+2][e]*x[i+3][e] > sum #Error is here
                sum = x[i][e]*x[i+1][e]*x[i+2][e]*x[i+3][e]
                i += 1
            else
                i += 1
            end
        end
        e += 1 #once you are out of the until statement, it increases e by 1 to check the next column
        i = 0  #resets i so it can go back to the zero
    end
return sum
end

print sumvertical(multiarray)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid has 20 rows. Your loop is actually trying to reach all the way to a 24rd row; that's because it goes through 21 iterations (`i` starts at 0, and goes until it equals 21), and each iteration reaches 3 beyond the current value of `i` (when you call `x[i+3]`). When `i` is 17, your code will break, because `x[i+3][e]` is trying to index into the 21st row of `x`. `i+3` is 20, but the highest available index is 19. So what happens is, `x[20]` returns `nil`, and then the `[]` method is called on `nil`, which generates your error.

Also, the standard library has a [transpose](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) method that you can call on your array. If you use it, you just need one method (`sumhorizontal`).  You can get the column sums with `sumhorizontal(multiarray.transpose)`.

One more thing... it looks like you're coming from a procedural language. Ruby has an extensive standard library and coding constructs that can save you a lot of time and keystrokes. There is typically no need to iterate with `while` loops and index variables in Ruby. `sumhorizontal`, for instance, can be written like this (it should really be called `producthorizontal`, though if you're trying to solve [Project Euler #11](http://projecteuler.net/problem=11):

```
def sumhorizontal(x)
  x.map { |r| r.each_slice(4).map { |s| s.reduce(:*) }.max }.max
end
```

Good luck with the rest of your Ruby learning journey!

Comment: Hey Sean,

Thank you for going above and beyond with the answer. I'm starting to learn Ruby as my first language so I appreciate it!